# Sending sms through java but gmail send error message

Tags: java, smtp, sms

I am sending sms through java from pc to mobile but gmail send error message as

> Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently

while my code is executed well no error and I am using telenor services so I found SMTP services as company name Telenor and SMTP formate as    phonenumber@mobilpost.no: And at the place of phone no I give my no for example 03440063315@mobilpost.no but I received message on gmail is given below:

```
Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain mobilpost.no by mx.online.no. [193.213.115.10].

The error that the other server returned was:
550 5.1.1 <03440063315@mobilpost.no>... User unknown

----- Original message -----

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
        h=date:from:to:message-id:subject:mime-version:content-type
         :content-transfer-encoding;
```

My java code is here,

package smstext;

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.Properties;
public class MailClient
{

public void sendMail(String from, String to,

String subject, String messageBody) throws MessagingException, AddressException
{

// Setup mail server
String host = "smtp.gmail.com";

String username = "rajiqbalbhatti@gmail.com";
String password = "password";

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");


// Get a mail session
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

// Define a new mail message

MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
message.setSubject(subject);

message.setText(messageBody);
// Send the message

Transport t = session.getTransport("smtps");
try {

t.connect(host, username, password);
t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

} finally {
t.close();
}
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
try
{
MailClient client = new MailClient();
String from="rajiqbalbhatti@gmail.com";

String to = "03440063315@mx.online.no";
String subject="Test";

String message="I'm testing. Do you see this?";
client.sendMail(from,to,subject,message);

}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}

}

}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like an issue with your code, as it is the mail server that is having an issue (`User unknown`). Can you send an email to this address manually (without your code and directly through an email client)?

Comment: Please also try to properly indent your code, so all text (such as `package name...` and the last `}` at the bottom of your question are in a nice, neat code block. Otherwise it is difficult for other users to easily read your code.